# how to translate \n properly using pandas to_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe with some text columns that contain `\n`. I tried to dump this dataframe to a tsv file but it seems like using `to_csv` method will create new lines when encountering `\n`. Is there anyway that I could have it dumped properly so each line represents one row in the dataframe, while preserving the `\n`s?